# want/prefer/would like something (to be)

Tags: meaning

**a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2** are the interpretations of **A,B,C** I guess.

This question is really important for me to understand English and read and make English sentences correctly!

I think A,B,C mean a1,b1,c1 if my coffee is not cold.

I think A,B,C mean a2,b2,c2 if my coffee is already cold.

> **A.I want my coffee to be cold.**

a1) I want to make my coffee cold.

a2) I want to keep my coffee  cold. = **I want my coffee cold.**

> **B. I prefer my coffee to be cold.**

b1) I prefer to make my coffee  cold.

b2) I prefer to keep my coffee cold. = **I prefer my coffee cold.**

> **C. I would like my coffee cold.**

c1) I would like to make my coffee cold.

c2) I would like to keep my coffee cold = **I would like my coffee cold.**

**Q1)** Do **A,B,C** mean either **a1,b1,c1** or **a2,b2,c**2 according to context? I think yes.

**Q2)** Do **"I want/prefer/would like/ my coffee cold"** sentences mean only **a2,b2,c2,** unlike **A,B,C** ? I think yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't paraphrase any of those sentences in any of those ways. I would assume the speaker meant:

> I like to drink my coffee cold.

Or, put even more simply:

> I prefer [iced coffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iced_coffee).

I think it's important to point out that a phrase like ***want*/*would like*/*prefer* something (to be)** is context-dependent, and one paraphrase won't necessarily apply to all situations.

- I prefer my boss to be cold.
- I prefer my coffee to be cold.
- I prefer my winters to be cold.

There are subtle difference to all of these.